# 10/2 pigtail question

Tags: electrical, wiring

USA Poster. Im by no means a professional but have done some amount of electrical work and am having a brain fart moment. I discovered a 10/2 splice inside a wall. No box, just spliced with some nuts and taped. I need to put it into a box, so I was going to undo the mess, add a box, "re-nut" correctly and then wanted to add a line of 12/2 for some outlets on that new wall. Can I just pigtail off the 10/2 junction and wire into a new line at 12/2? I was going to start the 12/2 from the pigtial and into a 20A GFCI and then run 2 outlets along the wall from that. Better way of doing it?

Comment: Find the breaker that the 10/2 is on.  If done right before it should be a 30 amp double breaker with the white wire changed to a second hot and not neutral.  Having a splice inside a wall makes it being done right quite iffy/suspect.  Depending on what you find, replacing with a single 20 amp breaker and moving the white wire to the neutral bus should be enough, plus the new box.

Comment: @crip659 shouldn't it be marked in some fashion too?  What if the OP adds his 12/2 and someone in the future comes by and says, "oh, this wire is 10 ga, I can swap the 20A breaked for a 30A!"

Comment: @Huesmann  It should be marked that 12/2 is on that circuit.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the circuit breaker ampacity.  Anything over 20 A is not allowed to use 12 ga circuit conductors nor 20 A receptacles.

Comment: A good thing that downgrading/reducing breaker size is allowed without needing to replace the over size wires/cable.